# how to apply custom function to each row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i have the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([(0,2,5), (2,4,None),(7,-5,4), (1,None,None)])

def clean(series):
    start = np.min(list(series.index[pd.isnull(series)]))
    end = len(series)
    series[start:] = series[start-1]
    return series
```

my objective is to obtain a dataframe in which each row which contains a None value is filled in with the last available numerical value.

so, for example, running this function on just the 3rd row of the dataframe, i would produce the following:

```
row = df.ix[3]
test = clean(row)
test

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

i cannot get this to work using the .apply() method, i.e. df.apply(clean,axis=1)

i should mention that this is a toy example - the custom function i would write in the real one is more dynamic in how it fills the values - so i am not looking for basic utilities like .ffill or .fillna

Comment: apply is not inplace and it returns a new DF, do you save this new df?

Comment: @Amen No there are completed filled rows that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apply method didn't work because when the row is completely filled your `clean` function will not know where to start the index from because of empty array for the given series.

So use a condition before altering series data i.e

```
def clean(series):
    # Creating a copy for the sake of safety 
    series = series.copy()
    # Alter series if only there exists a None value
    if pd.isnull(series).any():

        start = np.min(list(series.index[pd.isnull(series)]))

        # for completely filled row 
        # series.index[pd.isnull(series)] will return 
        # Int64Index([], dtype='int64')

        end = len(series)
        series[start:] = series[start-1]
    return series

df.apply(clean,1)
```

Output :

```
     0    1    2
0  0.0  2.0  5.0
1  2.0  4.0  4.0
2  7.0 -5.0  4.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Hope it clarifies why apply didn't work. I also suggest to take builtins to consideration to clean the data rather than writing functions from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

At first, This is the code to solve your toy problem. But this code isn't what you want.

```
df.ffill(axis=1)
```

Next, I try to test your code.

```
df.apply(clean,axis=1)
#...start = np.min(list(series.index[pd.isnull(series)]))...
#=>ValueError: ('zero-size array to reduction operation minimum 
#                which has no identity', 'occurred at index 0')
```

To understand the situation, test with lambda function.

```
df.apply(lambda series:list(series.index[pd.isnull(series)]),axis=1)
0        []
1       [2]
2        []
3    [1, 2]
dtype: object
```

And next expression puts the same value error:

```
import numpy as np
np.min([])
```

In conclusion, pandas.apply() works well but clean function doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like the fillna with backfill? I think this might be more efficient, if backfill meets your scenario..

i.e.

```
df.fillna(method='backfill')
```

However, this assumes a np.nan in the cells?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html